# How to restrict editing of certain cells in a DataTable editable in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to restrict certain cells in a DataTable from editing. I mean those fields are not allowed to be edited. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You mean certain columns ? If so , I think that you should remove the `<p:cellEditor>` wrapper from withing that column and leave only the `output` facet inside the `p:column`

Comment: Hi When I remove the <p:cellEditor> no value is displayed for that column. I am giving the changed snippet.Please Help.       <p:column>
        
          <f:facet name="output">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{videoList.referenceFileName}" />  
                </f:facet>  
                
       
         </p:column>

Comment: In the future questions, put your code and your attempt in the question as well. You also don't need to whine with "Please Help". Just ask the question the smart way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't use `<p:cellEditor>` then.

```
<p:column>#{videoList.referenceFileName}</p:column>
```

Note that the `<f:facet name="output">` is specific to `<p:cellEditor>`. You should remove it as well. Alo note that `<h:outputText>` is not necessary if you don't need to use any specific attributes on it.